# MySQL not creating table, keeps reporting syntax error which doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table in a MySQL database. I am using the command line of my server. I input:

```sql
test1;
CREATE TABLE people (ID int, name varchar(40));
```

...and it says:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE people (ID int, name varchar(40)); at line 1
```

I am very confused. I have even tried copy-pasting working examples of code, and I get the same result every time. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your syntax is valid in MySQL. The error comes from something else. Maybe you are running this as part of a script, or something else? You should so us your entire code.

Comment: What does `test1;` stand for? Maybe you meant `use test1;`?

Comment: test1 is my database which I set up as a test (hence the name). Yes, I did mean ```use test1; ``` — I think. Sorry, I am new (as in new this afternoon) to MySQL

Comment: It should work if you just replace `test1;` with `use test1`. Did you try it?

Comment: I can’t for a while; my computer needs to me moved out of the way for some time so I won’t be able to use it. Will try ASAP though, thank you

Comment: I tried it and it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all create database with the following syntax `CREATE DATABASE DATABASE_NAME` select the database like 
`USE DATABASE_NAME` 
then create table and the keyword in uppercase `CREATE TABLE people (Id INT, name VARCHAR(40));` or `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (Id INT, name VARCHAR(40));`